# Merge array if description and start time and end time are overlapping

Tags: php

I have an array made in this way:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Description] => A
            [StartTime] => 01:46:00
            [EndTime] => 02:25:00
            [Consume] => 10
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Description] => A
            [StartTime] => 02:25:00
            [EndTime] => 03:12:00
            [Consume] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Description] => A
            [StartTime] => 03:20:00
            [EndTime] => 04:05:00
            [Consume] => 100
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Description] => B
            [StartTime] => 04:05:00
            [EndTime] => 04:55:00
            [Consume] => 300
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Description] => B
            [StartTime] => 04:55:00
            [EndTime] => 05:03:00
            [Consume] => 100
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [Description] => B
            [StartTime] => 05:03:00
            [EndTime] => 05:55:00
            [Consume] => 200
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Description] => B
            [StartTime] => 06:00:00
            [EndTime] => 06:48:00
            [Consume] => 300
        )
)
```

Pratically i what to merge when:

1. Description is the same

AND

2. **EndTime** is the same of the next **StartTime** (for example [EndTime] => 02:25:00 is equal to [StartTime] => 02:25:00

If both condition match, merge and SUM Consume and take the first times and the last time. The expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Description] => A
            [StartTime] => 01:46:00
            [EndTime] => 03:12:00
            [Consume] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Description] => A
            [StartTime] => 03:20:00
            [EndTime] => 04:05:00
            [Consume] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Description] => B
            [StartTime] => 04:05:00
            [EndTime] => 05:55:00
            [Consume] => 600
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Description] => B
            [StartTime] => 06:00:00
            [EndTime] => 06:48:00
            [Consume] => 300
        )
)
```

My attempt, as request...

```
foreach ($array as $vals) {
    if (array_key_exists($vals['Description'], $res)) {
        $res[$vals['Description']]['Consume'] += $vals['Consume'];
        if ($res[$vals['Description']]['StartTime'] == "") {
            $res[$vals['Description']]['StartTime'] = $vals['StartTime'];
        }
        $res[$vals['Description']]['EndTime'] = $vals['EndTime'];
    }else{
        $res[$vals['Description']] = $vals;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

I don't need the numeric index (if make the things easier, we can use also the description as index if need)

Many thanks

Comment: pls write the code you tried to solve your problem

Comment: I have made a foreach with array_key_exist and check if there is a duplicate, then create another array based on that condition. But that code doesn't consider the thing of the Start Time and End Time and group everything, but in my case i need to check the hours

Comment: don't write a comment: edit your question and write the code you tried

Comment: Ok i have posted

Comment: Your expected result and your code are making me a little bit confused. What is real expected result of values in keys "Start time" and "End time"? Should start time for Unique description be the lowest of presented in the result? And same for End time, Should it be the biggest time of presented in array for unique Description?

Comment: When both condition match, I need the min StartTime and the max EndTime of the matched range.

Comment: @g-pane and what is expected result with these arrays? 
        [0] => Array
        (
            [Description] => A
            [StartTime] => 01:46:00
            [EndTime] => 03:12:00
            [Consume] => 30
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [Description] => A
            [StartTime] => 03:12:00
            [EndTime] => 04:05:00
            [Consume] => 100
        )
        [2] => Array
        (
            [Description] => A
            [StartTime] => 01:20:00
            [EndTime] => 01:46:00
            [Consume] => 255
        )

Comment: All merged. Since description is equal and [2] have 1:20 to 1:46, [0] is 1:46 to 3:12 and [1] is 3:12 to 4:05, all end time are equal to the next start time for that unique description. So the result will be 1 array, A description, StartTime 1:20, EndTime 4:05, Consume 385